# SetVisibility(false) does not work

Tags: openlayers-2

```
  layer_gesamt = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "Geoserver layers - Tiled", "http://mygeoserver/xyz/wms",
                {
                    LAYERS: 'myLayer',
                    STYLES: '',
                    format:  'image/png',
                    transparent: true,
                    tiled: true,
                    tilesOrigin : map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom,
                },
                {
                    buffer: 0,
                    displayOutsideMaxExtent: false,
                    isBaseLayer: true,
                    yx : {epsg : true}
                } 

          );
  layer_gesamt.setVisibility(false);


  map.addLayers([
     layer_gesamt,
     layer_selectable,
                 ]);
  map.setCenter(config.init_center.getCenterLonLat(),config.init_zoom);
```

I want the layer_gesamt in the example NOT to be displayed,  but to be loaded. That's why I set  `layer_gesamt.setVisibility(false);`. However, the layer is still displayed. What can I do?

Comment: Welcome to the GIS.SE. Can you give us a little more detail to help us answer your question? For example, what software and software version are you using? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! OpenLayers Version Numer: Release 2.14, GeoServer Version 2.4.4

Comment: Browser: Firefox 30.0

Answer (score 1):

What I found out: It works, when I create a new base layer and set the parameter `layer_gesamt.isBaseLayer = false`.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the Visibility BEFORE you add the layer to the Map so it has no effect ....

Try this ..

```
layer_gesamt = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        "Geoserver layers - Tiled", "http://mygeoserver/xyz/wms",
            {
                LAYERS: 'myLayer',
                STYLES: '',
                format:  'image/png',
                transparent: true,
                tiled: true,
                tilesOrigin : map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom,
            },
            {
                buffer: 0,
                displayOutsideMaxExtent: false,
                isBaseLayer: true,
                yx : {epsg : true}
            } 

      );

map.addLayers([
 layer_gesamt,
 layer_selectable,
             ]);

layer_gesamt.setVisibility(false);

map.setCenter(config.init_center.getCenterLonLat(),config.init_zoom);
```